# Systemd does not see external drive partition when running ExecStart command

Tags: mount, systemd

I am trying to run calibre-server at startup. Here is an example of the service content

```
[Unit]
Description=calibre Content server
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=root
Group=root
ExecStart=/opt/calibre/calibre-server "/path-to-mounted-external-hdd-partition/Calibre Library"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When I check the status of the service: `sudo systemctl status calibre-server.service`

I receive following message: `There is no calibre library at: /path-to-mounted-external-hdd-partition/Calibre Library`

However when I type: `sudo systemctl start calibre-server.service` it starts flawlessly.

My assumption was that partition and folder structure is not mounted/available at the time the service initially is ran. So I tried to replace **ExecStart** with `ExecStart=/test.sh` and content of **test.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

ls -la /path-to-mounted-external-hdd-partition/ 2> /out.txt >> /out.txt
```

the result stored in **out.txt** shows (*simplified for brevity*):

```
.
..
```

it seems the content of external hdd is empty at the time service is ran.

Why is that? How can I solve it?

**P.S.** I do not know if that is important but mounting is done via ubuntu/disks app and not by **/etc/fstab**

**P.P.S.**
`systemctl list-units | grep '\.mount'`

```
-.mount                   loaded active mounted   Root Mount
...
media-XXX-Storage.mount   loaded active mounted   /media/XXX/Storage
```

where **/media/XXX/Storage** is exactly what I described as **/path-to-mounted-external-hdd-partition**

Comment: Please [edit] to add the contents of `/etc/fstab`

Comment: Then, please [edit] with `systemctl list-units | grep '\.mount'`

Comment: I just added in "P.S." that fstab is not used.

Comment: "mounting is done via ubuntu/disks app" .. do you mean you manually click on the disks app each time to mount it?

Comment: @muru no, It takes care of it by default. However I can click there and unmount/mount again selected partition of external hdd

Comment: @DanielT I have added what you asked for in P.P.S.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*This answer depends on an assumption I made based on your edits and comments.*

*The mount you are using is an external mount, and you're depending on the GNOME's auto-mounting functionality. You don't have it configured in `fstab` nor as a systemd mount. This assumption is mainly because you mention `ls` on the directory shows an empty one, and that should not be the case. And the fact that the directory is under `/media/XXX`.*

Auto-mounted drives are not available during boot. You can confirm that by running the command from your edit `systemctl list-units | grep '\.mount'` in your test instead of the `ls` command. The result will not show the mount point. So adding them as dependencies will not have any effect, as those mount points are auto-generated after you log into your user session.

You can try experimenting with a user service instead of a system service. *In this case, you may find more success with [Daniel T's loop approach](https://askubuntu.com/a/1503373/).*

Create the service under `~/.config/systemd/user/your-service-name.service` and enable it while passing `--user` to the `systemctl` command.

```
systemctl --user enable your-service-name
```

Otherwise, the safer approach I recommend is adding an `fstab` entry (or a systemd .mount entry) to mount your drive. Then, as the other answers suggest, you can use it for `Requires` or `RequiresMountsFor`.

Ps. This is not directly related to your question, but if `ls -la /path-to-mounted-external-hdd-partition/` is showing you an empty directory during boot and you expect it to show you the content of your disk, it's because the directory exists. When the drive is mounted, the path is replaced from a local path to the mounted drive.

You can test this by completely unplugging the drive and trying the `ls` command and see if it results in a `No such file or directory` error.

Comment: I replaced script with what you said and result is exactly as you expected. It all makes sense now. Thank you for explaining me the process. Comprehension is more important to me than having a solution therefore I accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 4):

If you certain path should be mounted prior to running your service unit, you can also add the `RequiresMountsFor=` directive in the `[Unit]` section. This will check whether the path is available. So in the given case the complete directive would be
`RequiresMountsFor="/path-to-mounted-external-hdd-partition`.

For more information on this directive check the [systemd unit documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemd.unit.html#RequiresMountsFor=).

Comment: I have tried that already and it failed. I think the problem is not related to the mounting point being unavailable - it must be already mounted because script I tried shows empty content of mounting point folder, otherwise I would receive error such as "No such file or directory". The question is why partition's content of external hdd is unavailable.

Comment: @kkris1983 Not necessarly. The path probably exists as an empty directory, especially if it's showing you the wrong content. You can confirm this by unmounting your storage and checking if it shows an empty directory or "No such file or directory" when listing its content.

Comment: @Dan I am not sure if I comprehend what you said. After unmounting partition trying to list its content gives me what is expected "No such file or directory". However when the same partition is being listed with the script when executed by the service, it gives empty folder (. and .. entries). If mount point was not there in time I should receive "No such file or directory" too as a result of script being executed during service invocation.

Comment: @kkris1983 in your debug script (using `ls`), can you try running `findmnt /media/...`?

Answer (score 3):

Your calibre-server is starting before your mount is ready. Let's add the proper ordering dependency (EDIT please either skip to my second solution, or use [@noisefloor's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1503374/1004020) as a cleaner version of this first solution of mine):

```ini
[Unit]
Description=calibre Content server
After=network.target
# Added: wait for mount.
After=media-XXX-Storage.mount
# Added: Pull in the mount job if for some reason it's not
# started directly or indirectly by multi-user.target . Thanks @muru
Requires=media-XXX-Storage.mount

[Service]
Type=simple
User=root
Group=root
ExecStart=/opt/calibre/calibre-server "/path-to-mounted-external-hdd-partition/Calibre Library"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

If that doesn't work, you can add a loop on start to test for a file inside:

```ini
[Unit]
Description=calibre Content server
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=root
Group=root
ExecStart=/opt/calibre/calibre-server "/path-to-mounted-external-hdd-partition/Calibre Library"
# Added: wait for mount, workaround
ExecStartPre=/bin/bash -c "while ! grep -q '/media/XXX/Storage' /proc/mounts; do sleep 1; done"
# Don't let the above command time out
TimeoutStartSec=infinity

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: I tried already with "After" option but I added them in one line like following After=network.target media-XXX-Storage.mount. However I will try loop solution.

Comment: You should also have a `Requires` for that mount unit

Comment: One line / multiple lines are the same to systemd. The `After=` is the clean solution. The loop solution with `ExecStartPre` is whatever I could think of when it didn't work. If the loop times out, you might need to increase or disable `TimeoutStartSec=`

Comment: @muru Added, thanks. I thought `multi-user.target` already eventually includes the mount unit.

Comment: @muru I tried before with RequiresMountsFor= which did not work. Just now I tried Requires= and it failed too. Weird thing is that script I described above returned empty folder for the mounting point, so I assume it had been mounted already but content was not "available" at the time.

Comment: @DanielT your workaround with "spinlock" works. However I would like to understand what is going on. Do you think static mount with fstab is required? Why mounting point's content is empty when script I described was executed?

Comment: @kkris1983 Is that partition over NFS or something? But definitely, fstab is more reliable. Which version of my workaround? The one with the spinlock on the mount, or the version with some_file_you_know_should_exist?

Comment: @DanielT: both "while loop" and TimeoutStartSec work.

Comment: Oh well, I just put both things I mentioned in edits to my answer. If you want to get to the bottom of this, you could replace `ls` with `mount` in your `test.sh`

Comment: @DanielT it is external drive connected via USB. However there is another service (samba/smb) that uses its partitions.

Comment: @kkris1983 Have you tried an `After=` and/or `Requires=` specifying that other service?

Comment: @DanielT I made mistake by saying that TimeoutStartSec worked - it does not. However "while loop" works flawlessly.

Comment: @kkris1983 The `TimeoutStartSec` is supposed to be used ***together with*** my `ExecStartPre` while loop. There have been many edits to my answer, so you can read it for the most up-to-date version

Comment: yes, I have tried both After and RequiresMountsFor before I initially asked the question, and then I tried Requires. All these options failed. Please check my comment under @noisefloor answer. I think there is different issue than mounting point - it seems to be ok, but its content is empty at the time service is being ran.

Comment: @DanielT: I have tried updated first solution - it fails as expected. I tried these options already. I chose your workaroud solution with "ExecStartPre=/bin/bash -c "while ! grep -q '/media/XXX/Storage' /proc/mounts; do sleep 1; done"" because it does not require creating artificial file just to wait on it. Thank you for your help. Still I wonder what is the cause behind all that.

Comment: I rolled back to the version that works for you. About the cause, I'm guessing it might have something to do with udisks since it's `/media`

Answer (score 0):

After setting static mount in `/etc/fstab` it works with settings as you advised.

```
[Unit]
Description=calibre Content server
After=network.target
RequiresMountsFor=/media/XXX/Storage

[Service]
Type=simple
User=user
Group=user
ExecStart=/opt/calibre/calibre-server "/home/XXX/Storage/Calibre Library"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Thank you all for help.